# Can the session expire when using a function of an included file?

Tags: php, session

I've got this session variable, which was initiated in `index.php`

```
<?php
  $sid = session_id();
  if (empty($sid) {
    session_start();
  }

  //value of the variable can be changed and saved before coming back to the index
  if(!isset($_SESSION['context'])){
    $_SESSION['context'] = 1;
  }

  //...
?>
```

Later a script is used to create or update a database entry.

`entryupdate.php`:

```
<?php
  include_once("template.php");
  /*....*/

  $sid = session_id();
  if (empty($sid)) {
    session_start();
  }

  /*....*/

  //Create a new entry, context is not given in the $input_object at this point.
  $template = new Template($input_object);
  $context = $template->getContext();
?>
```

`template.php` is a script where only the Template Object is defined, so I don't call `$session_start` in it, my rationale being that it would always be called by the scripts including it, as it is in the case I'm describing here. Here is the relevant code:

```
<?php
  class Template
  {
    private $m_context;
    //other private parameters

    function __construct($arguments_object){
      if(!is_null($arguments_object)){
        /*....*/
        $this->m_context = $arguments_object->context;
        /*....*/
      }
    }

    /*....*/

    function getContext(){
      if(!empty($this->m_context)){
        return $this->m_context;
      }else{
        //this would be our case, as the parameter was not initialized yet.
        return $_SESSION['context'];
      }
    }

    /*....*/

   }
?>
```

Now, a colleague stumbled on an error and upon investigation, I found out that the `$context` was set to `NULL`. When I tried to reproduce the issue, the context was correctly initialized. And to be honest, for the few years the tool has been used, it is the first time this kind of issue was encountered.

I've also checked, at no point I am unsetting this particular session variable.

Am I making a false assumption there, in thinking that `template.php` would find the session variable when the session was started in `entryupdate.php` where it was included and used?

Comment: The `$_SESSION` is supposed to be a GLOBAL, so if started in the outer code it should be available to included code as you suggest

Comment: @RiggsFolly so what could make that the value of the variable gets lost? I've been told that the session was at most 10 minutes long.

Comment: maybe disk is full and session is not correct written to disk

Comment: @FatFreddy There is still about 30GB of disk space free on the server

Comment: I would suggest that some code somewhere has fiddled with the session.

Comment: @RiggsFolly but what kind of code could fiddle with the session like that? How can I track what happened? As I said, this particular session variable is never `unset` in my code.